# Android. Flickering keyboard

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments, keyboard, android-softkeyboard

the question is simple. I have an edittext in xml with

```
 android:inputType="number"
```

My task is to open the keyboard after opening the page (its fragment witch include only one editText)

There are no problems with calling keyboard. It appears at startup, everything is ok. But there is 1 artifact.

My keyboard is flickering (often but not always).
First a keyboard with text(default inputType) is shown and then very quickly changes to number type.

Can I fix it? To avoid flickering / switching

Comment: this might be a problem with your device. Try running on other devices. But you can change it programmatically `field.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_TEXT);
`

Comment: ok, i will try.